# how to dispay the guestures with image in mobile application in cordova?

Tags: jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

[image]

I want to display text like this in my cordova app. Is there any plugin present to show these gestures with images or is there any some other way.
Your help may be useful to me.

Comment: Why don't you just show some images? I don't know why you would need a plugin here...

Answer (score 0):

I had found multiple plugins for that but keep in mind it will work only with that which has gestures facility. Please have look to some plugins.[cordova-plugin-shake](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-shake)

Its code example :

```
var onShake = function () {
  // Fired when a shake is detected
};

var onError = function () {
  // Fired when there is an accelerometer error (optional)
};

// Start watching for shake gestures and call "onShake"
// with a shake sensitivity of 40 (optional, default 30)
shake.startWatch(onShake, 40 /*, onError */);

// Stop watching for shake gestures
shake.stopWatch();
```

I also have find an other one .[cordova-plugin-gesture](https://github.com/gabhi/cordova-plugin-gesture)

```
   javascript:cordova.gesture.onGesture('tap', {coords: {x: 400, y: 300}}); 
    javascript:cordova.gesture.onGesture('slide', {coords: {x: 400, y: 300}});
```

Comment: It has only called when the event detected. how to show the finger images with information  use of any cordova plugin???

Comment: Read this http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/gestures/ its only provide few gestures by the help of plugin. I don't think so that there is such a plugin.